# Google Spreadsheets : how do i manage the automatic increment when extending formula to other cells?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have, I hope at least, a very simple question.

I have a simple sheet with the 3 first columns being a table of results, and a bunch of options that I can fill in some columns on the right. Obviously, the values in the table are supposed to change when I change the different options.

The formulas are very simple : =B2+F9 (each value in the table is based on the previous entry, the first one being specified in the options.

When I select the cell, grab the little square on its bottom right and drag it down it generates something like this :

```
=B2+F9
=B3+F10
=B4+F11
=B5+F12
```

It's basically incrementing each reference... wich is the probem I face as the F9 reference is an option and should not change.

What I want basically is something like :

```
=B2+F9
=B3+F9
=B4+F9
=B5+F9
```

Thus incrementing the B column, but not the F9 cell.

I tried to "hard-write" some of the first cells, kind of telling him "keep this F9" but without any success :(

How am I supposed to do this ? :'(

Answer (score 4):

Use absolute references for that. In your case, you'd have the following:

```
=B2+F$9
```

The `$` symbol means that the row is absolute, and should not change when you extend the formula. So, it would generate:

```
=B2+F$9
=B3+F$9
=B4+F$9
...
```

If you want the column to be fixed, you can reference it like `$B2`, for example. And if both the column and the row must be fixed, you'd use `$B$2` syntax.